# canvasjs not displaying bars in chart

Tags: jquery, json, canvasjs

I am working on a stackedColumn chart in canvasjs, feeding it data from an $ajax response and am not getting the columns displayed. I put together a fiddle showing what I am working with:

https://jsfiddle.net/azjuzuu0/4/

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>



$('input:button').on('click', function () {
var response = <view fiddle for json>

var JSONresponse = JSON.stringify(response).substring(6, JSON.stringify(response).length - 2);

            JSONresponse = JSONresponse.replace(/\\/g, '');
            var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(JSONresponse);

            // QuoteStatus, AssignedTo, Amount

            var currentAssignedTo; //this lets us keep track of who we're working on. 
            //    If the name of hte current obj is not hte currentassignedto, then we are on to a new person

            var assignedToCount = -1;

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                {
                    title: {
                        text: "Total of Jobs per Status",
                        fontFamily: "arial black",
                        fontColor: "#695A42"
                    },
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    toolTip: {
                        shared: true,
                        content: function (e) {
                            var str = '';
                            var total = 0;
                            var str3;
                            var str2;
                            for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++) {
                                var str1 = "<span style= 'color:" + e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "'> " + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: $<strong>" + e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong><br/>";
                                total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
                                str = str.concat(str1);
                            };
                            str2 = "<span style = 'color:DodgerBlue; '><strong>" + (e.entries[0].dataPoint.x) + "</strong></span><br/>";
                            total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
                            str3 = "<span style = 'color:Tomato '>Total:</span><strong> $" + total + "</strong><br/>";

                            return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
                        }
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        valueFormatString: "$#",
                        gridColor: "#B6B1A8",
                        tickColor: "#B6B1A8",
                        interlacedColor: "rgba(182,177,168,0.2)"
                    },
                    data: []
                });

            $.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {

                if (obj.AssignedTo !== currentAssignedTo) {
                    //we're either on the first row or are moving into a new person   color: colors[assignedToCount],
                    currentAssignedTo = obj.AssignedTo;
                    assignedToCount += 1;
                    chart.options.data.push({ type: 'stackedColumn', showInLegend: true, name: obj.AssignedTo, dataPoints: [] });
                } //end if

                chart.options.data[assignedToCount].dataPoints.push({ y: obj.Amount, label: obj.quoteType });

            }); // end $.each                       

            chart.render();
        })
```

some source material I am leaning on: https://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=https://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/column/coal_reserves/

https://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=https://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/column/google_revenue/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan Wier,

Datapoint y-value should be number, but in json its stored as string. So, changing it to number in json itself or while parsing should work in your case.

```
chart.options.data[assignedToCount].dataPoints.push({ y: Number(obj.Amount), label: obj.quoteType });
```

Please check [this updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/azjuzuu0/6/).

Comment: That worked thank you! Gota remember your data types! The other issue I guess I didn't mention above is that the labels for the X axis are not displaying, it is only showing numbers, though I am providing a label in the dataPoints array.

Comment: Dan, I observed that the "quoteType" which you are passing as label is not available in the json object. Because of which it is returned as "undefined" and the numbers will be shown.

Comment: It's amazing the things you can over look...I intended to use QuoteStatus there....thanks for the eyes!